How to get the tensorboard url in VertexAI
from google.cloud import aiplatform

...

    aiplatform.init()
    aiplatform.start_upload_tb_log(tensorboard_experiment_name=..., logdir=...)

In VertexAI this prints

View your Tensorboard at https://europe-west1.tensorboard.googleusercontent.com/experiment/projects+826303096232+locations+europe-west1+tensorboards+8125232599590240256+experiments+small-test-of-output-dario-figueira-trainfromcsvpipeline-20240603114325-trainclassifier

How to get this link programatically?
(I cannot reproduce this locally, I'm failing to find any documentation or examples on the matter, and ChatGPT is not helping, just hallucinating)
EDIT: A flabbergasting behaviour:
    tensorboards = aiplatform.Tensorboard.list(order_by="create_time desc")
    for tensorboard in tensorboards:
        print("TensorBoard Details:")
        for attribute, value in tensorboard.__dict__.items():
            print(f"{attribute}: {value}")
        print("\n")

Shows only tensorboards from 3 days ago and older
